# Azure B2C - Custom policies / Add registration step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to create a custom policy that will add additional step during the sign up/in process to requires more information.

I added:
1. New ClaimsProvider

```
<ClaimsProviders>
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="GetCity">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Sign In</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>

</ClaimsProvider>
```

2. New claim type

   city
               string
               city
               TextBox
3. New output claim in SignupSignIn RP
4. Additional steps before send claims during the UserJourney - SignUpOrSignIn

After the registration there is no authentication and there is no step for "city" data.

Any idea where is the problem? I already configured app insight, but there is no errors there.

Comment: Can you confirm you are entering into the orchestration step for getting this additional information from the user? Did you add a pre-condition to the orchestration step, for example?

Comment: Yes, I added orchestration step <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="city" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GetCity" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

Comment: Are you getting any error? Could you please post the policy URL here to test?

Comment: Thanks Marcelo! There was a missing configuration from my side. Now everything works as expected and I have two steps registration.

Comment: Thanks Iva! Can you share what you did?

Comment: Hi @MarceloP.DiIorio-MSFT, the problem was two missing configurations: 1) because "city" claim is not built-in claim, I didn't refer the claim with "extension_" prefix; 2) my TrustFrameworkExtenstion.xml doesn't contain the right ApplicationId and ObjectId of WebApp-GraphAPI-DirectoryExtensions application. Now everything works as expected. I will share the whole solution as answer of the question.